# What are the odds of getting a desired result on a specific throw?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

I was asked this question recently in a D&D campaign and didn't know how to begin approaching it. In short: what is the likelihood you get a result on a specific roll rather than at least once?

For example, if you roll a 20 sided die 4 times, what are the odds that you get a 20 on the final roll specifically?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, I mean what are the odds that the first 3 rolls aren't a 20, but the last one is. The order of the rolls matters, where in 4 rolls the first 3 are specifically not 20s, and the last specifically is. Would that simply be $(\frac{19}{20})^3\times\frac{1}{20}$, treating each as a separate chance and multiplying them together?

Comment: If you only care about a specific roll, the number of times you roll the dice is irrelevant.  Are you asking the question you intend to?

Comment: I believe so. My intent is that _only_ the last roll is the 20. So what are the odds you roll 4 times, where the first 3 rolls aren't a 20, and the last one _is_ a 20?
I think it's similar to how you can find the odds that a roll happens at least once, except I care about which specific roll grants the result, rather than it being any one of the 4 rolls made.

Comment: Your answer is correct. If you had specified that it should occur only on the third roll, eg, the *Pr* would be $\frac{19}{20}\frac{19}{20}\frac{1}{20}\frac{19}{20}$